# How to create a post html page for a working php app?

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I am learning to code and I made a simple php app that makes a phone call given a hard coded from and to number (it uses the Twilio api - www.twilio.com).

The code looks like below:

```
<?php

require_once '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';

use Twilio\Rest\Client;

$sid    = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$token  = "your_auth_token";
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);

$call = $twilio->calls
       ->create("+15558675310", // to
                "+15017122661", // from
                array("url" => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml")
       );

print($call->sid);
```

The above php app works just fine.

What I want to now do is create an html page that takes a dynamic to number (static from number) and when I hit the submit button, the call should go through. However I have no clue how to make that happen except for the following snippet from the twilio documentation (https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call#create-a-call-resource)

*Calls can be made via the REST API to phone numbers, SIP addresses, or client identifiers. To place a new outbound call, make an HTTP POST request to your account's Call resource.*

From that, I understand that I have to make a post call via an html form page, but where do I start the post call to the URL as shown in the above documentation (*https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Calls.json*) and where do I keep the authentication details in the php app that I copy pasted above? The documentation says that I've to provide a for and to number when making the post call, again I am not sure where to provide that.

```
<html>
 <body>
  <form action="twilioCall.php" method="post"> 
   From: <input type="number" name="from">
   To: <input type="number" name="to">
   <input type="submit">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Any help/pointers would be very helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code provided should work fine. In your php script you can access your from and to number by calling $_POST["from"]' and $_POST["to"]

Comment: For more information about posting data in webforms see https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Answer (score 0):

In order to place calls in your browser with your laptop/computer with Twilio you need [Twilio Client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript) library and you also need to install the [Twilio PHP Library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/php).

This assumes that you have already created a Twilio account and purchased a twilio number with voice and sms capabilities. I assumed that you have already installed Twilio PHP library.

When you will press on "makeCall" button, you will be prompted to use your microphone. Select whatever microphone you use to speak with your laptop. Put on some headphones and call yourself. Lots of fun!

Do this :

1. Find your [Twilio Account SID](https://www.comm100.com/livechat/knowledgebase/where-do-i-find-the-twilio-account-sid-auth-token-and-phone-number-sid.html) and Primary Auth Token.
2. Create a [TwiML APP](https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/twiml/apps/create) and point the VOICE REQUEST URL to 
   `https://EXAMPLEmywebsite.com/voice.php`

**voice.php**

```
<?php
include '../twilio/Twilio/autoload.php';

use Twilio\Twiml;

$response = new Twiml;

//THE PHONE NUMBER YOU HAVE PURCHASED
$TWILIO_CALLER_ID = '';

// get the phone number from the page request parameters, if given
if (isset($_REQUEST['To']) && strlen($_REQUEST['To']) > 0) {
    $number = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['To']);
    $dial = $response->dial(array
            ('callerId' => $TWILIO_CALLER_ID, 
                                   'record' => 'record-from-answer'
        ));

  if($number == "English Queue" || $number== "Spanish Queue") {
     $dial->queue($number);
  } 
  elseif (preg_match("/^[\d\+\-\(\) ]+$/", $number)) {
     $dial->number($number);
    } else {
      $dial->client($number);
    }
} else {
    $response->say("Thanks for calling!");
}

header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo $response;
```

**dialpad.php**

```
  <!-- jquery -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Twilio Client IMPORTANT -->
   <script src="https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/client/v1.6/twilio.min.js"></script>

    //display phone logs
    <div id="log"></div>

    //simple basic dialpad
    <input id="phoneScreen" placeholder="enter phone number">

    //dial button
    <button id="makeCall" class="btn btn-success btn-dial">
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/25/000000/ringer-volume.png">
    </button>

    //hang up button
    <button id="endCall" class="btn btn-danger btn-dial">
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/25/000000/end-call.png">
    </button>

    //include twilioClient.js
    <script src="twilioClient.js"></script>
```

**twilioClient.js**

```
$(function () {

    log('Connecting Agent Station...');

    $.getJSON('./token.php').done(function (data) {
        log('Agent Station Connected.');
        //console.log('Token: ' + data.token);

        // Setup Twilio.Device
        Twilio.Device.setup(data.token);

        Twilio.Device.ready(function (device) {
            log('Phone Ready For Call');
        });

        Twilio.Device.error(function (error) {
            log('Agent Station Error: ' + error.message);

            //update call log

        });

        Twilio.Device.connect(function (conn) {
            log('Success! Call Established.');
        });

        Twilio.Device.disconnect(function (conn) {
            log('Call ended.');
        });

//bind button to answer incoming call?
        document.getElementById('answerCall').onclick = function () {
            // get the phone number to connect the call to
            var queueName = document.getElementById('queuename').value;
            var params = {
                To: queueName
            };
            log('Connecting agent to ' + params.To + '...');
            Twilio.Device.connect(params);
        };

        setClientNameUI(data.identity);
    })
            .fail(function () {
                log('Could not connect agent station to server!');
            });

    // Bind button to make call
    document.getElementById('makeCall').onclick = function () {

        // get the phone number to connect the call to
        var params = {
            To: document.getElementById('phoneScreen').value
        };

        log('Calling ' + params.To + '...');
        Twilio.Device.connect(params);

        Twilio.Device.connect(function (connection) {

            //retrieve call sid
            var callSid = connection.parameters.CallSid;

            //retrieve phone number
            var phonenumber = $('#phoneScreen').val();

        });
    };

    // Bind button to hangup call
    document.getElementById('endCall').onclick = function () {
        log('Hanging up...');
        Twilio.Device.disconnectAll();
    };

});

// Activity log
function log(message) {
    var logDiv = document.getElementById('log');
    logDiv.innerHTML += '<p>&gt;&nbsp;' + message + '</p>';
    logDiv.scrollTop = logDiv.scrollHeight;
}
```

**token.php**

```
<?php
include '../twilio/Twilio/autoload.php';
use Twilio\Jwt\ClientToken;

// choose a random username for the connecting user
$identity = "Caller".rand(9, 99999).round(microtime(true) * 1000).date('Y');

 //twilio account sid
 $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID = 'YOUR_TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID';
 //twilio auth token
$TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN = 'YOUR_TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN';
//twilio app sid
$TWILIO_TWIML_APP_SID = 'YOUR_TWIMl_APP_SID';

$capability = new ClientToken($TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, $TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);
$capability->allowClientOutgoing($TWILIO_TWIML_APP_SID);
$capability->allowClientIncoming($identity);
$token = $capability->generateToken();

// return serialized token and the user's randomly generated ID
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array(
    'identity' => $identity,
    'token' => $token,
));
```